# Android Studio java: listview em uma activity, mandar informações para ela de outra activity

Tags: java, android

O código da lista:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    //Atributos
    private SQLiteDatabase bancoDados;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itensAdaptador;
    private ArrayList<String> itens;
    private ArrayList<Integer>ids;
    private Button adicionar;
    private EditText txt;
    private ListView lista;
    private String Name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adicionar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);

        // Criando Banco dados
        bancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase("apptarefas", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        //Criando Tabela do banco
        bancoDados.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tarefas(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,tarefa VARCHAR)");

        recuperarTarefas();
        adicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String texto = txt.getText().toString();
                salvarTarefa(texto);
                txt.setText("");
            }
        });
        //Clicar e remover tarefa
        lista.setLongClickable(true);
        lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                removertarefa(ids.get(position));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    //Metodos
    public void salvarTarefa(String texto){
        try {
bancoDados.execSQL("INSERT INTO tarefas (tarefa)VALUES('" +texto+ "')");
recuperarTarefas();
}catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void recuperarTarefas() {
        try {
            //Recupera as Tarefas
            Cursor cursor = bancoDados.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tarefas", null);

            //Recuperar os ids das colunas
            int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
            int indiceColunaTarefa = cursor.getColumnIndex("tarefa");

            //criar adaptador
            ids=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            itens= new ArrayList<String>();
            itensAdaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    android.R.id.text2,
                    itens);
            lista.setAdapter(itensAdaptador);


            //listar as tarefas
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor != null) {

                //Log.i("Resultado", "Tarefa: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaId));
                Log.i("Resultado", "Tarefa: " + cursor.getString(indiceColunaTarefa));
                itens.add(cursor.getString(indiceColunaTarefa));
                ids.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(indiceColunaId)));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void removertarefa(Integer id){
        bancoDados.execSQL("DELETE FROM tarefas WHERE id="+id);
        recuperarTarefas();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Enviando valores

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
            String descricao = itens.get(position);
            Integer id = ids.get(position);

            Intent intent= new Intent(Main2Activity .this, SUA_OUTRA_ACTIVITY.class);
            intent.putExtra("descricao", descricao);
            intent.putExtra("id ", id);
            startActivity(in1);
        }
    });
```

//recebendo valores

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String descricao = getIntent().getStringExtra("descricao");
        Integer id= getIntent().getIntegerExtra("id", 0);

    }
```

Espero que ajude!